# How to only show certain nav bar elements in a certain path (ruby logic)

Tags: html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Currently I have the following in my header layout:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Random Name<%#= image_tag('RandomName.jpg') %></a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-container-right">
    <% if current_path != root_path %>  
      <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "About",    about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact",    contact_path %></li>
        <li>  
            <% if current_user.present? %>
                <%= link_to 'Sign Out',destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path %>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Register Now!', new_user_registration_path %><% end %></li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

This gives me an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_path' for #<#<Class:0x5699580>:0x3d9f6b0>
```

I want to show the elements on the right on all pages except if the user is on the root_path

I also tried:

```
<% unless root_path %>
```

which at least didn't give me an error but the elements are not shown on any page at all.

What is the proper syntax in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
unless params[:controller] = 'home' && params[:action] = 'index'
```

Where you need to specify your controller and action associated with root path.

Comment: This was a bit confusing: I tried putting this: <% unless params[:controller] = 'pages' && params[:action] = 'landing' %> but it did not work...

Comment: try adding `<%= params.inspect %>` and add results to your question.

Comment: Sorry I am new at this. Where do I add params inspect? on my header? or on the actual page where the information is not displaying?

Comment: @user3597950 - We want to see what those params are, so you need to add it anywhere it will be displayed. Maybe just before the navigation bar?

Comment: [at] = @ | After struggling for a while to figure it out. I solved the problem through another method. I put <% unless [at]ready %> in my header and then put [at]ready = true in my controller action that I didn't want the contents rendered in. That has seemed to work. Thanks for attempting to help! Appreciate it!